EngFormatter for minor ticks on a log scale
I want to change the formatting of tick labels without changing which ones are displayed. This code gets me halfway there:
plt.plot(range(5), [5e3, 7e3, 9e3, 11e3, 13e3], marker='o')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())


But if I try to change the formatting of the minor tick, I get a bunch of additional labels that I don't necessarily want:
plt.plot(range(5), [5e3, 7e3, 9e3, 11e3, 13e3], marker='o')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())


To recap, how do I get a y-axis where the labels are '10 k' and '6 k'?

You don't really need to use the minor ticks. They are off by default, which is why those extra values appear if you change their format.
Anyway, if you want specific values for the ticks, just set them explicitly with set_xticks:
plt.plot(range(5), [5e3, 7e3, 9e3, 11e3, 13e3], marker='o')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.gca().yaxis.set_ticks([6e3, 10e3])
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())

# just for the example, let's add minor ticks at 7k and 11k
plt.gca().yaxis.set_ticks([7e3, 11e3], minor=True)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())

Output:

